# Get Path to node with specific id

Tags: c#, algorithm, recursion, search

I am having serious problems getting my head around solving a task that - from the offset - seemed quite simple.

I have an object hierarchy built on a composite pattern. The objects look like this:

```
public class Org
{
  public string Id;
  public string Name;
  public List<Org> Orgs;
}
```

I need to find an `Org` element with a specific `Id` and return the path to the `Org` object.

The hierarchy is *not* a binary tree - each `Org` object can have zero or more child `Org`'s.

So if the hierarchy was this

```
Org1 (abc)
  Org2 (cvf)
  Org3 (grf)
    Org4 (uyk)
      Org5 (suf)
    Org6 (vxl)
    Org7 (bmd)
  Org8 (pes)
```

The desired outcomes would be this

```
Org7 bmd --> Org1,Org3,Org7
Org2 cvf --> Org1,Org2
Org4 uyk --> Org1,Org3,Org4
```

Note that Org4 is not a leaf node.

I can find a lot of solutions on searching binary trees, but I am having a hard time keeping track of my "current node" when traversing the hierarchy - Especially when switching out from Org2 to Org3 in earch of e.g. "Org5 (suf)".

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

:-)

**Solution:**

I added a small modification to @Funk's suggestion - it works for me now :-)

```
static void TraversePathToId(LookupTableItem org, string id, List<string> path)
{
    if (org.Id == id)
    {
        path.Add(org.Name);
    }
    else
    {
        foreach (var child in org.ChildItems)
        {
            TraversePathToId(child, id, path);
            if (path.Any())
            {
                path.Add(org.Name);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}

static List<string> GetPath(LookupTableItem root, string id)
{
    List<string> path = new List<string>();
    TraversePathToId(root, id, path);
    path.Reverse();

    return path;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main gotcha with recursion is that for your current node, you're always on top of the call stack. With all previous (parent) nodes on lower levels, waiting for execution to return. This means you can pass your results back to them. And determine the path in one go (in reverse order).

```
class Program
{
    static void TraversePathToId(Org org, string id, List<string> path)
    {
        if (org.Id == id) path.Add(org.Name);

        foreach (var child in org.Orgs)
        {
            TraversePathToId(child, id, path);
            if (path.Any())
            {
                path.Add(org.Name);
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    static List<string> GetPath(Org root, string id)
    {
        List<string> path = new List<string>();
        TraversePathToId(root, id, path);
        path.Reverse();

        return path;
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Org root = new Org("Org1", "abc")
        {
            Orgs = new List<Org>
            {
                new Org("Org2", "cvf"),
                new Org("Org3", "grf")
                {
                    Orgs = new List<Org>
                    {
                        new Org("Org4", "uyk")
                        {
                            Orgs = new List<Org>
                            {
                                new Org("Org5", "suf"),
                            }
                        },
                        new Org("Org6", "vxl"),
                        new Org("Org7", "bmd"),
                    }
                },
                new Org("Org8", "pes"),
            }
        };

        GetPath(root, "suf").ForEach(name => Console.Write($"{name}\t"));

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

public class Org
{
    public Org(string name, string id)
    {
        Name = name;
        Id = id;
        Orgs = new List<Org>();
    }
    public string Name { get; }
    public string Id { get; }
    public List<Org> Orgs { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Hi @Funk, thank you :-) ... but it doesn't work exactly. It works for leaf nodes, but for non-leaf nodes, it multiplies the identified node when iterating over any children. The problem is that it adds a node when it find a match, but still traverses any children ... and regardless of finding any matches, does a path.Any() and thereby adding any subsequent nodes.I added my modification to your code (out-commented yours) to show the solution that works even for non-leaf nodes.

Answer (score 1):

BFS or DFS will do the job.
you can keep a global array of ID's to mark the visited Org, when you get to an object call the search recursively on the unvisited objects.
To get the path, use backtrack.